# Handle arithmetic operator in Java

Tags: java

I have four classes for handling math operations: `Plus`, `Multiply`, `Divide`, `Minus`

my input is like this:

```
1, 2, +
```

Now my question is this : How can we determine the type of operator then call the correct class?(implement without if-else or switch-case)

Comment: If you are trying to build a Reverse Polish Notation parser, then it I think you are heading down the wrong path by creating classes for the operators.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Map<Character,Object>` where you can store character and object to calculate in single structure and access later with character only without any `if-else` or `switch`.

```
Map<Character,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put('+', plusObject);
map.put('-', minusObject);
map.put('*', multiplyObject);
map.put('/', divideObject);
```

> Now my question is this : How can we determine the type of operator
>   then call the correct class?

`map.get(character)`  it will return the object according to the character and `null` otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, how can access to character?

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface for the operation objects. Have them implement it.

```
public interface OperationObject {
    public int eval(int a, int b);
}
```

Then use it like this or similar

```
public class Handler {
    private HashMap<Character, OperationObject> operationMap = new HashMap<Character, OperationObject>();

    public Handler() {
        operationMap.put('+', new additionObject());
        operationMap.put('-', new subtractionObject());
        operationMap.put('*', new multiplicationObject());
        operationMap.put('/', new divisionObject());
    }

    public int doOperation(int number1, int number2, char operation) {
        return operationMap.get(operation).eval(number1, number2);
    }
}
```

This is the best I could do, without writing the operation classes for you.

doSomething should be your method in your classes that does the operation, really you should use an interface like defined above.