# How do I use an Interface as Map’s Value?

Tags: java, dictionary

I want to write an application that handle the math operator.
I define an interface like this :

```
public interface Operator
{
    public double calculate(double a,double b);
}
```

For every operator i write a class like this:

```
class Plus implements Operator
{
    public double calculate(double a,double b)
    {
        return firstNumber + secondNumber;
    }
}
```

```
class Minus implements Operator
{
    public double calculate(double a,double b)
    {
        return firstNumber - secondNumber;
    }
}
```

And so on...
I use `Map` like this:

```
static Map<String,Operator> map = new HashMap<String,Operator>();
```

I don't know how to use `put` and `get`. For example,

```
map.put("-",...);
map.put("*",...);
map.put("/",...);
```

Comment: This is already answered in your previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32154165/handle-arithmetic-operator-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do `new Operator()`, just create an instance of the subclass ((`Plus`, `Minus`, etc.) itself. In other words:

```
map.put("-", new Minus());
map.put("*", new Multiply());
map.put("+", new Plus());
```

---

To call `calculate`, just do:

```
double result = map.get("+").calculate(a, b);
```

Comment: sry in get method how do I call calculate mathod?

Comment: Thanks alot your answer help me

Comment: @golitini Don't forget you can accept this as the answer to your question by clicking the hollow checkmark next to the voting buttons in the top left corner.

Answer (score 0):

While using `put` you need to provide one of the implementation of `Operator` interface as value in Map:

```
Operator plus = new Plus();
map.put("+",plus);
```

And while retrieving you will be sure that you will receive an `Opeartor` (It may be plus (`+`), minus(`-`) or anything else but an `Opeartor`).

```
Operator op = map.get("+");
double a = 10;
double b = 5;
op.calculate(a,b)  // It will call respective method based on operator.
```

Comment: sry in get method how do I call calculate mathod?

Comment: After calling `get` you will get an `Operator` (actually one of the implementations of `Operator`) and then just call it.